# What is the use of EF code-first if we can't create stored proceudres, views from it?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I have been working with EF and a code-first approach for 1 month. I learnt that other than tables, there is no direct way to create DB objects like stored procedures, views, user-defined types, etc.

Below is the only way to add stored procedures manually in `Up` method of migration file.

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.Sql(@"your create procedure statement");
}
```

In this case, does anyhow I would need to go to SQL Server Management Studio to make sure that SQL query is compiled correctly and then paste in above code line.

Also in terms of implementing security on basis on role is also not sure how to do it in EF Core code first. I am not sure why many projects are using. We are thinking to go back to traditional ADO.NET approach because of all these limitations.

1. Can someone please tell me why should I use EF Core code-first and how to create DB objects other than tables without help of SQL Server Management studio.
2. Deployment is also easier in DACPAC compare to EF Core code first.

Comment: Why not just stick to Database First, if you use EF Core Power Tools you also get stored procedures and functions mapped - and you can reverse engineer from a .dacpac!

Comment: _"why should I use EF Core code first"_ - you should not if the tool does not suit your needs.

Comment: Also note that not everyone is using SQL Server, Visual Studio and SSMS.

Comment: @ErikEJ My question was on generic side. If we have this much limitations in EF then why its so popular.

Comment: @GuruStron My question was on generic side. If we have this much limitations in EF then why its so popular.